# Any luck mixing gear sheds/porches/garages with different brands of tents?

Tags: tents, tarp-tents, rain-gear

We have an REI half dome 2 plus tent, but during our last trip it rained quite a bit. While this tent has two vestibules, they are low and were mostly filled with gear, so that when we unzipped to get out, our stuff got wet. It would have been nice to have an area where you could take a minute to get it together before/after going out in the rain.

Problem is, there is no porch or gear shed attachment for this model. I've seen ones for Nemo, MSR, Marmot, etc. but am unsure how specific the designs are for those models. Has anyone had any luck with this? I've considered using a tarp, too, but when the rain is blowing sideways this isn't a great solution. Suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have the HD2+ myself, and I doubt you will find anything. Have you thought about carrying a tarp? I usually carry one for my gear.  If it's raining, it gives lots of room outside the tent for cooking too. Just be sure you learn to set it up before you commit to using it 

Comment: We did (see OP) and ended up getting one for the time being, but would prefer a vestibule with a side-oriented (not upward oriented) door for the rain, and also something we can set up to crouching height (not just a simple triangular shape) even when there are no trees around. Guess it's a lot to ask for backpacking :P

Comment: You need to be really lucky to find something that matches a tent that had no specific accessories. People i know that had those problems ended changing tents or making their own mods (if its just adding an extra triangle of fabric to the vestibule for more room the mod is pretty trivial). If REI is anything like the MEC we have here in Canada you could go there with the tent and they will try all they have to see what fits. Although in a bad storm with lots of wind a very compact design is worth some discomfort. Have you tried getting ready outside while wearing a poncho? its not that bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the situation you describe, mismatched gear is not going to provide what you want.  If the rain is blowing sideways and/or hard enough to get past your tarp then it will most likely also blow in the gaps inevitably left by the mismatched gear.  Unfortunately the answer is the news most people least want:  You have the wrong tent for what you are looking to do.

Comment: That's what I figured, although several appear to attach with ribbons and hooks to the main frame, and then the main concern is to get the rainfly to cover that area well: http://cdn.campsaver.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/900x900/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/g/s/gs3.jpg